# Python target for Java grammar in antlr

Tags: java, python, antlr4

I want to run a Lexer for Java in Python using Antlr

For Antlr4, I am using the Java8 grammar from https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/java8.

I am generating the parser using

`java -jar antlr-4.5.2-complete.jar -Dlanguage=Python2 ./Java8.g4`

Now if I look at the generated Java8Lexer.py, it contains

`return Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(Character.toCodePoint((char)_input.LA(-2), (char)_input.LA(-1)))`

I don't think that the type cast is valid python and it throws a syntax error there when I use it.

I had a similar problem using antlr3 using a antlr3 java 1.6 grammar. It generated

`boolean isSomething = something`

which is also not valid Python.

Am I missing something? Is there any way to use a Java Lexer in Python using antlr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove strings wich start with [Character.isJavaIdentifierStart](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java8/Java8.g4#L1742) from your Java8 grammar.

Comment: Remove *and* replace with their Python equivalents, as the predicates are significant to the proper operation of those lexer rules.

Comment: I left the first part of the rule i.e. character classes [a-z] etc.. but removed the Character.* stuff and it works now. Thanks!